# How do I turn this into a for loop from range(0, 99) instead of user input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Help, How do I turn this into a for loop from range(0, 99) instead of user input?

```
amount = int(input("enter the amount in cents from 0 to 99: ")) 
cents = amount
quarters = amount // 25
amount = quarters % 25  
dimes = amount // 10  
amount = amount % 10  
nickels = amount // 5  
amount = amount % 5  
pennies = amount  
print(cents, quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies)
```

Comment: For the record, you can simplify the code using `divmod`. `quarters, amount = divmod(amount, 25)`, `dimes, amount = divmod(amount, 10)`, `nickels, pennies = divmod(amount, 5)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your current logic has a bug. If you try `99` as the input, the result will be
`99 3 0 0 3` ie. 3 quarters and 3 pennies, which is NOT 99 cents.

You're doing a % on `quarters` instead of `amount`

If you fix that and then put it in a standard for loop, you'll get the following:

```py
for amount in range(100):
    cents = amount
    quarters = amount // 25
    amount = amount % 25  
    dimes = amount // 10  
    amount = amount % 10  
    nickels = amount // 5  
    amount = amount % 5  
    pennies = amount  
    print(cents, quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies)
```